# Android Push Notification using GCM, PHP and MySQL

Tags: android, push-notification

I am having issue with push notifications. I am trying Android Push Notifications using Google Cloud Messaging (GCM), PHP and MySQL following instructions mentioned in AndroidHive. My device is registered with GCM and can see the record in the database however when send push notification, not able to receive on the device. I am posting the link which i have followed. Please advise if i am missing anything.  http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Manifest file:

```
AndroidManifest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.androidhive.pushnotifications"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <!-- GCM requires Android SDK version 2.2 (API level 8) or above. -->
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <!-- GCM connects to Internet Services. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.androidhive.pushnotifications.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.androidhive.pushnotifications.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!-- Network State Permissions to detect Internet status -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <!-- Permission to vibrate -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <!-- Main activity. -->
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <!-- Register Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Main Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>

                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.androidhive.pushnotifications" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
    </application>

</manifest>


index.php

index.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){

            });
            function sendPushNotification(id){
                var data = $('form#'+id).serialize();
                $('form#'+id).unbind('submit');               
                $.ajax({
                    url: "send_message.php",
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: data,
                    beforeSend: function() {

                    },
                    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                          $('.txt_message').val("");
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .container{
                width: 950px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                padding: 0;
            }
            h1{
                font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 24px;
                color: #777;
            }
            div.clear{
                clear: both;
            }
            ul.devices{
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            ul.devices li{
                float: left;
                list-style: none;
                border: 1px solid #dedede;
                padding: 10px;
                margin: 0 15px 25px 0;
                border-radius: 3px;
                -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
                -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
                box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
                font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                color: #555;
            }
            ul.devices li label, ul.devices li span{
                font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 12px;
                font-style: normal;
                font-variant: normal;
                font-weight: bold;
                color: #393939;
                display: block;
                float: left;
            }
            ul.devices li label{
                height: 25px;
                width: 50px;               
            }
            ul.devices li textarea{
                float: left;
                resize: none;
            }
            ul.devices li .send_btn{
                background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#0096FF), to(#005DFF));
                background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#0096FF), to(#005DFF));
                background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #0096FF, #005DFF);
                background: linear-gradient(#0096FF, #005DFF);
                text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
                border-radius: 3px;
                color: #fff;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        include_once 'db_functions.php';
        $db = new DB_Functions();
        $users = $db->getAllUsers();
        if ($users != false)
            $no_of_users = mysql_num_rows($users);
        else
            $no_of_users = 0;
        ?>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>No of Devices Registered: <?php echo $no_of_users; ?></h1>
            <hr/>
            <ul class="devices">
                <?php
                if ($no_of_users > 0) {
                    ?>
                    <?php
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($users)) {
                        ?>
                        <li>
                            <form id="<?php echo $row["id"] ?>" name="" method="post" onsubmit="return sendPushNotification('<?php echo $row["id"] ?>')">
                                <label>Name: </label> <span><?php echo $row["name"] ?></span>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                                <label>Email:</label> <span><?php echo $row["email"] ?></span>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                                <div class="send_container">                               
                                    <textarea rows="3" name="message" cols="25" class="txt_message" placeholder="Type message here"></textarea>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="regId" value="<?php echo $row["gcm_regid"] ?>"/>
                                    <input type="submit" class="send_btn" value="Send" onclick=""/>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </li>
                    <?php }
                } else { ?>
                    <li>
                        No Users Registered Yet!
                    </li>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Register.php

```
<?php

// response json
$json = array();

/**
 * Registering a user device
 * Store reg id in users table
 */
if (isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["regId"])) {
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $gcm_regid = $_POST["regId"]; // GCM Registration ID
    // Store user details in db
    include_once './db_functions.php';
    include_once './GCM.php';

    $db = new DB_Functions();
    $gcm = new GCM();

    $res = $db->storeUser($name, $email, $gcm_regid);

    $registatoin_ids = array($gcm_regid);
    $message = array("product" => "shirt");

    $result = $gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message);
    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    echo $result;
} else {
    // user details missing
}
?>
```

Comment: You'll have to post more details if you want help. Do you get a successful response from Google's GCM server? In addition, please show us your manifest and relevant client code. Posting a link to a tutorial doesn't help.

Comment: as the code is very big i had to post only the link. Yes i get response from server saying that device is registered. I will edit the question with code and manifest file.

Comment: Thanks for posting the manifest. It looks fine. What I meant, when I asked about the response, is what response you get when you send a message from your server to GCM (I didn't ask about the registration).

Comment: Unfortunately. I don't get any response.i will post index.php which i am using to send notification.

Comment: Are you saying `echo $result;` prints nothing?

Comment: yes..does not print anything

Comment: @user3091035 try generating new API key... Even i faced same issue and by creating new API key issue got fixed.

Answer (score 3):

You can test GCM push notification with online tools as well. With these online tools you will know whether you have issue in your code OR using wrong credentials (GCM key).

- http://pushtry.com/
- http://apns-gcm.bryantan.info/
- http://www.pushwatch.com/

Apart than this, you can test with chiarg's script and this script will show the status (Failure and success with other details).

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue when I was trying to implement push notification using above link.
After couple of day nonsense R&D i reached to solution that I provide the wrong google key in php code. I was getting some 404 status error.

Then the solution is

- Login in to Google Console Account [Link](https://console.developers.google.com)
- Create new Project
- Under APIs & Auth-> select API and enable Google **Cloud Messaging for Android** services
- Then under APIs & Auth -> select "Credentials"-> "Create New Key" in Public API access section
- Select "Browser Key" under "Create New Key" dialog. and again click "Create" (without adding anything in textarea)
- It will get new API key.

Copy this api key paste it into register.php code.

```
 $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . 'AIzaSyDa4aTJMblZixlatAZjdDXxCf_2mJqc3WM', // HERE IT IS DEMO KEY
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
```

Now you can try sending Notification. It should work.

Enjoy... Happy Coding.

Comment: Sorry sachin, i have added the code and it is not working. I will post register.php file for your reference.

Comment: Have you change GOOGLE_API_KEY, which looks something like this AIzaSyDa4aTJMblZixlatAZjdDXxCf_2mJqc3WM

Can you check that google registration key is added into database or not?

Comment: yes. Reg id is added to database. can i send the completed code for reference?

Comment: I have pasted the google api key where it is mentioned.

Comment: Did you create "Browser Key"? or any other key? It won't be worked with any other keys. 
Do not use "Android Key"

Comment: i did copy the Browser key. no luck:(

Comment: if you can send me the code that you have used i will compare and see.please email to user3091035@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working script

```
<?php
class GCM {

    //put your code here
    // constructor
    function __construct() {

    }
    /**
    * Sending Push Notification
    */
    static function send_notification($data=array()) {

        // Set POST variables
        $ = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
        $apiKey = 'API key register via google console';
        $data = array(
            'registration_ids' => array($data['device_token']),
            'data' =>array("message"=>$data['message'])
        ); 

        $headers = array(
            'Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
        // Open connection

        $ch = curl_init();

        // Set the , number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_, $);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));

        //echo json_encode($data);
        // Execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }
        print_r($result);
        // Close connection
        curl_close($ch);
    }
}
```

Here is 2 IMP things to consider

1) API KEY which is registered via google console must be valid.

2) device token of android device in which push will be received